# Converting splat attributes from Slim to ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, slim-lang

I'm new to Rails and was tasked to change a legacy code that's written in slim to ERB. Everything was going smoothly, but when I reached the splat attributes and found myself blocked.

The slim I'm trying to convert is like this:

```
doctype html
html lang="en" *data_turbolinks_messages
  head
```

The respective controller is:

```
DATA_TURBOLINKS_MESSAGES = {
    'data-turbolinks-messages' => ENV.fetch('TURBOLINKS_MESSAGES')
  }.freeze  

def data_turbolinks_messages
    DATA_TURBOLINKS_MESSAGES
end
```

And the final HTML I've expected is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-turbolinks-messages="VariableValue" lang="en">
<head></head></html>
```

I've tried using `slimrb --rails -e` but the outcome has many slim helper objects like `::Slim::Splat::Builder.new(_slim_splat_filter)` and I don't know how to write that in ERB.

Other solutions I've tried (shooting in the dark here.. again, new to Rails)

- `<%= **data-turbolinks-messages -%>`
- `<%= **data-turbolinks-messages.html_safe -%>`
- `<%= *data-turbolinks-messages %>`
- `<%= data-turbolinks-messages.to_s %>`
- `<% *data-turbolinks-messages.html_safe %>`
- `<%= tag.html lang:'en' data-turbolinks-messages %>`
- `<%= tag.html lang:'en' data: data-turbolinks-messages do %>...<% end %>`
- `<%= tag.html lang:'en' data:{data-turbolinks-messages} do %>...<% end %>`

Is there a way to bring that hash as key-value tag parameters, hopefully without changing the controller, which has other dependencies?

thanks!

Comment: This in invalid syntax: `<%= data-turbolinks-messages.anything %>`. Do you mean `<%= data_turbolinks_messages %>` ?

Comment: You mean in my attempts? As data-turbolinks-messages is a hash, it worked when I tried... the results of having the `.to_s` was the same as not having: `To be precise, the output of both ways I get (with and without .to_s) is <html lang:'en'="" {&quot;data-turbolinks-messages&quot;=">&quot;VariableValue&quot;}" `, which isn't really what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I had to change the controller so the hash uses symbols as keys

```
DATA_TURBOLINKS_MESSAGES = {
    :'data-turbolinks-messages' => ENV.fetch('TURBOLINKS_MESSAGES')
  }.freeze  

def data_turbolinks_messages
    DATA_TURBOLINKS_MESSAGES
end
```

Once I did that, I could splat the hash in ERB with helper tags. I also used `content_tag` instead of `tag`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%= content_tag(:html, **data_turbolinks_messages, :lang => "pt" ) do %>
...
<% end %>
```

I still have no idea whether or not this is a good or bad solution, as I went through trial and error, so any new answers are welcome!